# Using VSTS Rest API, how do you create a Markdown widget?

Tags: json, rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to use [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/dashboard/widgets/create?view=vsts-rest-5.0) to create (or Update...same issue) a "Markdown" widget on a dashboard in VSTS.

> `POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}/widgets?api-version=5.0-preview.2`

Using the below `JSON` body, per the sample, I'm constantly getting `eTag` errors? I've also tried updating an existing Markdown Widget with no luck, so that's why I've turned to delete & create.

```
{
    "name": "Markdown",
    "position": {
      "row": 1,
      "column": 4
    },
    "size": {
      "rowSpan": 2,
      "columnSpan": 2
    },
    "settings": "# AK Markdown\nAdd content using the markdown widget.\n- **Bold**\n- *Italic*\n- [Links]()",
    "settingsVersion": {
      "major": 1,
      "minor": 0,
      "patch": 0
    },
    "dashboard": {
      "eTag": "18"
    },
    "contributionId": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.Microsoft.VisualStudioOnline.Dashboards.MarkdownWidget"
  }
```

See below screenshot for Fiddler's `Request`/`Response`.

[image: Screenshot]

My goal is at the end of various Build/Releases, I want to create/update a widget with markdown that shows specific data for our users/stakeholders. Many whom are not skilled with VSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reasons that will throw 407 conflict error when add/create a new widget, position and eTag, for example, if there is already a widget in the same position, the it will throw error if you add/create a new widget to that position again, so you need to make sure there isn’t the widget at target position

note: the widget’s size can affect the others position, for example, a widget’s position is column:1; row:2 and size is rowSpan:2, then the next widget’s position can be column:3; row:2, but can’t column:2; row:2

The simple way to deal with this issue is remove position property from json data.

Regarding eTag value, you can call [Get a dashboard REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/dashboard/dashboards/get?view=vsts-rest-5.0), the result contains **eTag** property, just use this value on other REST API, also, you can remove dashboard property from json data when create a widget.

Regarding update widget, you can call [Get Widget REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/dashboard/widgets/get%20widget?view=vsts-rest-5.0), then the result contains **eTags** and **dashboard** properties, after that using these value in update widget REST API.

Comment: After removing the position parameter, it worked! I was unable to get the update to work, so I was deleting and re-creating. I used the exact position property from the Markdown widget I was deleting, but that did not seem to work for create, so it makes me think there may be a bug there? Or maybe I was doing something wrong. I still can't get the `Update` to work, but I'm getting a different error. I posted a new question since it's a new error if you know what the issue is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374422/using-vsts-rest-api-how-do-you-update-a-markdown-widget .

Comment: Also, how did you know it's a 407 error? I don't see that # anywhere?