# Using VSTS Rest API, how do you Update a Markdown widget?

Tags: json, rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to use [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/dashboard/widgets/update%20widget?view=vsts-rest-5.0) to Update a "Markdown" widget on a dashboard in VSTS.

Using the below `JSON` body, per the sample, I'm getting `Value cannot be null` (see below)?

### Error

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value
>   cannot be null.\r\nParameter name:
>   widget","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException,mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}At
>   C:\Users\alex\OneDrive\Documents\Scripts\VSTSPowershell\VSTSAuthenticateAndInvoke.ps1:36
>   char:23+ ...   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method $method
>   -ContentType  ...+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
>   WebException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

### JSON

```
{
    "id": "3b52e9ed-576e-4985-82ae-8e80b22a4b4d",
    "eTag": "1",
    "name": "Markdown",
    "size": {"rowSpan":2; "columnSpan":2},
    "settings": "# AAAAK Markdown\nAdd content using the markdown widget.\n- **Bold**\n- *Italic*\n- [Links]()",
    "settingsVersion": "@{major=1; minor=0; patch=0}",
    "dashboard": {
        "eTag": "35"
      },
    "contributionId": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.Microsoft.VisualStudioOnline.Dashboards.MarkdownWidget"
}
```

### Fiddler `Request`/`Response`

[image]

My goal is simply to find & update a Markdown widget with new display content. It's a newly created widget, so `eTag=1`, which I verified with a Get Dashboard along with the `WidgetId`, and the `eTag=35` is what the Dashboard is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
"size": {"rowSpan":2; "columnSpan":2},
```

to

```
"size": {"rowSpan":2, "columnSpan":2},
```

Comment: Took me a while to spot it in your answer, not even the original sample in the question :)

Comment: No idea - I'm not the topic starter and don't have the env to test - it has just occurred to me that it was not that easy to spot.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Wow thanks for spotting this. The JSON was generated from PowerShell using `ConvertTo-Json` and `ConvertFrom-Json`. I noticed it would also do things like `"position": "@{row=1; column=4}",` So I didn't exactly hand-key the mistake...I wonder why PS does that?